# I keep getting this error when I boot up VSCode on Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

Everytime I open up the application, it asks me "The Background extension does not have permission to backup to the VSCode folder, run command using administrator permissions?

```
EROFS: read-only file system, copyfile '/private/var/folders/jx/215lljkx02s7x9spyty8dvgc0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2774D50B-C1FA-4DA4-8311-CA9B095D29A9/d/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js' -> '/private/var/folders/jx/215lljkx02s7x9spyty8dvgc0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2774D50B-C1FA-4DA4-8311-CA9B095D29A9/d/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main-backup.js'"
```

I select "Yes" then it gives me this error:

```
OS: darwin 23.4.0
Using command: cp -f /private/var/folders/jx/215lljkx02s7x9spyty8dvgc0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2774D50B-C1FA-4DA4-8311-CA9B095D29A9/d/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js' '/private/var/folders/jx/215lljkx02s7x9spyty8dvgc0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2774D50B-C1FA-4DA4-8311-CA9B095D29A9/d/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main-backup.js' && cp -f '/private/var/folders/jx/215lljkx02s7x9spyty8dvgc0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2774D50B-C1FA-4DA4-8311-CA9B095D29A9/d/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/product.json' '/private/var/folders/jx/215lljkx02s7x9spyty8dvgc0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2774D50B-C1FA-4DA4-8311-CA9B095D29A9/d/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/product-backup.json'

Error
Command failed: cp -f '/private/var/folders/jx/215lljkx02s7x9spyty8dvgc0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2774D50B-C1FA-4DA4-8311-CA9B095D29A9/d/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js' '/private/var/folders/jx/215lljkx02s7x9spyty8dvgc0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2774D50B-C1FA-4DA4-8311-CA9B095D29A9/d/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main-backup.js' && cp -f '/private/var/folders/jx/215lljkx02s7x9spyty8dvgc0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2774D50B-C1FA-4DA4-8311-CA9B095D29A9/d/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/product.json' '/private/var/folders/jx/215lljkx02s7x9spyty8dvgc0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2774D50B-C1FA-4DA4-8311-CA9B095D29A9/d/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/product-backup.json'
cp: /private/var/folders/jx/215lljkx02s7x9spyty8dvgc0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2774D50B-C1FA-4DA4-8311-CA9B095D29A9/d/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main-backup.js: Read-only file system
```

I have tried using sudo to run it, but I still end up with the same issue

Comment: what is this "background extension"? Is it a VS Code extension? some kind of Desktop application / extension?